# How can I show help_text attribute through for loop in my template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegistratiion(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    name  = forms.CharField(help_text="80 Char Maximum")
```

**views.py**

```
def showFormData(request):
    fm = UserRegistratiion(auto_id="my_%s")
    return render(request, "blog/login.html", {"form":fm})
```

When i use this in my template it works fine and my help_text shows in span tag..

```
<form action="">
<div>
{{form.as_p}}
</div>
```

But, whwn i use for loop

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<div>
{{field.label_tag}}
{{field}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

help_text doesn't show how can i get this?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<div>
{{ field.label_tag }}
{{ field }}
{{ field.help_text }} <!-- new -->
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
<div>
{{ field.label_tag }}
{{ field }}
{% if field.name =='name' %}
{{ field.help_text }} <!-- new -->
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It is working I have upvoted you, but why it doesn't show in input tag as an attribute, even other attributes show..

Comment: @TariqAhmed you mean this <input type="submit"> ? If yes you have to add this yourself after the forloop inthe form tag.

Comment: It should show help_text just to write {{field}}  . Why not show? Why we need to explicitly write that attribute..

Comment: @TariqAhmed please read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields